# Element distorts when scrolling, and sometimes doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, distortion

EDIT:

A colleague worked out what was wrong. It was because the `aside` element had `z-index: 2`. Although it is fixed now, I'm not sure why that `z-index: 2` was causing these issues in the first place. If anybody knows why, I'd like to know.

---

I'm having a rather odd issue on a website i'm working on. When on the architecture section, I click on one of the blocks to open the project, and it works. Almost. When one of the projects is open, the `aside` on the left does not scroll correctly. It distorts and splits up. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Architecture section]

But the odd thing is, the interiors section, which uses the same code, works fine. I have just recently finished re-coding the news section with a new design and more features, so it could be something to do with that. But, so far, I have found no connection with other sections on the page.

There are other errors on that specific page too. The Close button and next button hover events don't seem to be firing. However, if I open Dev tools and set the width of the close button to 29px, the hover event works, and the cross goes orange.

You can access the site at http://dev.guyhollaway.co.uk/

If anybody has any ideas, I'd be very thankful.

This happens on Google Chrome on both Windows and OS X.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser? I can't reproduce this issue in Chrome on Mac OS.

Comment: Google Chrome on OS X and Windows.